# Angular 2 doesn't bind when change a variable using setter method

Tags: typescript, angular

I have the following AngularJS 2 cide and my problem is that when calling the setter method `setCourse` the new data "java" doesn't reflect to the UI.
So it's supposed to show "java" instead of "x,y,z" but it doesn't.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({selector:'course',
template: `
<ul> <li *ngFor="#x of courses">  {{ x }}</li> </ul>`
})
export class CourseComponent {
private courses: string[] = ['x ' , 'y ' , 'z'];

public setCourse(courses:string[]){
    this.courses = courses;
}

}
```

---

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CourseComponent} from './course.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><course></course>',
    directives:[CourseComponent],
    providers:[CourseComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
private newCourses:string[];

public constructor(courseComponent: CourseComponent){
    courseComponent.setCourse(['java'])
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're trying to change variable of different instances.

You could leverage ViewChild to get the instance CourseComponent which is defined within your template and only after ngAfterViewInit hook you can fire changes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><course></course>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(CourseComponent) courseComponent;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.courseComponent.setCourse(['java'])
  }
}
```